# Adding the same superscript to element with identical attribute

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a function that will dynamically add a superscript based on a DOM elements attribute. This function needs to add the same superscript number if the attribute value is identical.

HTML:

```html
<span class='disclosure' data-id="test1">Footnote</span>
<span class='disclosure' data-id="test2">Another footnote</span>
<span class='disclosure' data-id="test3">Another footnote</span>
<span class='disclosure' data-id="test1">Another footnote</span>
```

JS:

```js
let disclosureElement = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-id]'),
    disclosureArray = [],
    footnoteNumber = 1;

function createDisclosureArray() {
    for (let i = 0, max = disclosureElement.length; i < max; i++) {
        let fragmentId = disclosureElement[i].dataset.id;
        let uniqueIdString = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
        disclosureArray.push({
            fragmentId: fragmentId,
            anchorId: fragmentId + '-' + uniqueIdString,
            superScript: footnoteNumber
        });
        anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
        anchorTag.setAttribute('href', '#' + disclosureArray[i].anchorId);
        anchorTag.setAttribute('class', 'disclosureAnchor');
        sup = document.createElement('sup');
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        const superScript = fragment
            .appendChild(anchorTag)
            .appendChild(sup);
        superScript.textContent = '[' + disclosureArray[i].superScript + ']';
        disclosureElement[i].append(fragment);
        footnoteNumber++;
    }

    return disclosureArray;
}

createDisclosureArray();
```

The above will loop through the array of objects and add the superscript. However, I need it to add a matching superscript for all elements that have identical data-id attributes.

For example,
`<span class='disclosure' data-id="test1">footnote</span>` and `<span class='disclosure' data-id="test1">Another footnote</span>` should have the same superscript footnote number since their data-id attributes have the same value.

Comment: I can not answer your question but I noticed that in your JavaScript you have a comma after the first three variable assignments. It should be a semicolon. Also for the second and third assignments you do not use `const` or `let` or `var`.

Comment: Also you don't invoke `createDisclousreArray()`

Comment: Sorry, I copied this snipped from a larger javascript file. I should have done a better job cleaning it up for this post. 

I invoke the function later in the js file Im working on.

Comment: OK I just got it working. It might be good to put it in a snippet so you have it working in your question. In your for loop you could create an object of key dataset.id and value footnoteNumber. You only add a new key value pair to this object for unique dataset.ids. Then when you get a dataset.id you have had before instead of using footnoteNumber you use the value in the object to populate the superscript property of the disclosureArray object. I am sure there are much  more elegant solutions but that is all I can think of. It is quite complicated and I am only quarter of the way there...

Comment: When I say I got it working I do not mean I have solved the problem. Just got the superscripts to show up.

Comment: I tried to edit your code so it is in a working snippet but I got "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!"

Comment: Can you also provide an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a `previous` object which contains dataset.ids as keys with footnoteNumbers as values. I only add a key value pair if the dataset.id is not already in the `previous` object. Then I put the value of the current dataset.id key's value (ie the original footnote assigned to that dataset.id) into a variable called `n`. I use assign superScript to the value of `n`

Here is the snippet:

```js
         let disclosureElement = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-id]');
        let disclosureArray = [];
        let footnoteNumber = 1;

        let previous = {};
        let n;       
        
        function createDisclosureArray(){    
            for (let i = 0, max=disclosureElement.length; i < max; i++) {

                if(!previous.hasOwnProperty(disclosureElement[i].dataset.id)){
                    previous[disclosureElement[i].dataset.id] = footnoteNumber;
                }
                n = previous[disclosureElement[i].dataset.id];


                let fragmentId = disclosureElement[i].dataset.id;
                let uniqueIdString = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2,8);
                disclosureArray.push({
                    fragmentId: fragmentId,
                    anchorId: fragmentId+ '-'+ uniqueIdString,
                    //superScript: footnoteNumber

                    superScript: n

                });
                anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
                anchorTag.setAttribute('href', '#'+disclosureArray[i].anchorId);
                anchorTag.setAttribute('class', 'disclosureAnchor');
                sup = document.createElement('sup');
                const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                const superScript = fragment
                    .appendChild(anchorTag)
                    .appendChild(sup);
                superScript.textContent = '['+disclosureArray[i].superScript+']';
                disclosureElement[i].append(fragment);
                footnoteNumber++;
            }

            return disclosureArray;
        }
        createDisclosureArray();
```

```html
    <span class='disclosure' data-id="test1">Footnote</span>
    <span class='disclosure' data-id="test2">Another footnote</span>
    <span class='disclosure' data-id="test3">Another footnote</span>
    <span class='disclosure' data-id="test1">Another footnote</span>
```